# Hiawatha CGI: writing to the client as soon as a command gets executed

Tags: cgi, hiawatha

I have a CGI script run by Hiawatha web server that needs to

1. return some data to the client,
2. do some system work (may take 20-30 seconds)
3. and then return yet more data.

So far I haven't been able to achieve this result: the script doesn't write data as the commands get executed, rather, it writes everything in a single shot when its execution ends. Is it even possible to achieve with Hiawatha what I described above? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: you need to set the `WaitForCGI = yes` option in the config file.